# Handle WP RegistrationMagic submission data in PHP after SQL query

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types

I am using Wordpress with the Registration Magic Plugin.
Everything works fine so far and the submissions are stored in the MySQL database. After querying for specific submissions, by e. g.

`$submission_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rm_submissions WHERE user_email = '$current_user_mail' AND form_id = 11", OBJECT);`

I get the results and also may echo the 'data' value that looks similar to this (what datatype is it?):

```
a:3:
{
i:911;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Email";s:5:"value";s:21:"email@domain.de";s:4:"type";s:5:"Email";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:917;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:14:"ValueLabelString1";s:5:"value";s:5:"22080";s:4:"type";s:6:"Number";s:4:"meta";N;}
i:918;O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:5:"label";s:23:"ValueLabelString2";s:5:"value";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:6:"Number";s:4:"meta";N;}
}
```

How can I parse it into a format that allows me to read the "value" of a specific "ValueLabelString" by something like:

`echo $new_format_data["ValueLabelString1"]`

Thank you and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is the serialized representation (that is the result of the serialization PHP performs before storing data objects) and you only have to unserialize it before processing as a stdClass.

For further information follow https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186379/how-to-decipher-the-following-array

Happy Coding!